# Печать html страниц без служебной информации

Tags: html, печать

При печати из различных браузеров обычно выводится дополнительная информация (url и тд) с различными настройками (размеры полей и тд). Существует ли возможность устанавливать свои настройки (в коде) при печати: например скрыть url и задать размеры бумаги?

Answer (score 2):

вот это помогло:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
@page {
 margin: 0cm;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
тест печати
</body>
</html>
```